# .css Background image appear on hover in list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

On start, I would like to say sorry, but I'm new in this.
I'm trying to achieve something like in [THIS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69842270/screenshots/AAwebdproblems/fadein.jpg) image

I already have a script setup to make the block grow on hover, but have a big problem with making the background image appear (I want to, just for start, make it display. Then I'll play with the jQuery animation).
So my question is: What would be the best way to attach a background to the il block, and make it appear only on hover (properly scaling ofc)?

I tried to have the image in a different block, making it pos. absolute, but it would get messed up with more then one element.

Here's the code for the list's html:

```
<ul id="AktContainer">
           <li class="Akt">President killed a baby!
        </li>

           <li class="Akt">President killed a baby!</li>
           <li class="Akt">President killed a baby!</li>
           <li class="Akt">President killed a baby!</li>
           <li class="Akt">President killed a baby!</li>

    </ul> <!--AktContainer -->
```

And the css for inner elements:

```
#AktContainer{
display:block;
width: 95%;
float:right;
height: 88%;
}

.Akt{
display: block;
width: 330px;
height: 12%;
background-color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

And also, the script for scaling individual il elements:

```
$('.Akt')
.on('mouseover', function(){
    var div = $(this);
    div.stop(true, true).animate({ 
        margin: -10,
        width: "+=20",
        height: "+=20",


    }, 'fast');
})
.on('mouseleave', function(){
    var div = $(this);
    div.stop(true, true).animate({ 
        margin: 0,
        width: "-=20",
        height: "-=20",


    }, 'fast');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fade the background image and keep the text with just one element. You could use pseudo elements (`:before` and `:after`) and animate that but those pseudo elements are not accessible trough jQuery.

So your best bet is to either use 2 elements or animate the pseudo elements with css and then just `.addClass('active')` on mouseover and remove it on mouseleave.

Of course you could use css only for just a hover.

Here's a css only demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/qvvycqb6/

Comment: Wow. This is great. Thanks. But what if I'd want more than one image? I mean for every menu element to have a different one?

Comment: Add unique classes `one`, `two`, etc for each `Akt` and use css to change the bakcground. `.Akt.one:before{...}` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/qvvycqb6/1/